# Reevaluate closure of question 515115 (meaning of cylinder light on computer) – not a typical "guessing game" question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

[Question 515115, "What does this light shaped like a cylinder mean?"](https://superuser.com/questions/515115/what-does-this-light-shaped-like-a-cylinder-mean), was closed by a moderator as off-topic on the grounds that it is a visual identification question.

However, I have several concerns about this closure:

- The item to be identified is not a piece of hardware or a port, but an icon for an indicator light.
- The indicator light in question is commonly found on many PCs, and the cylinder symbol has a nonobvious meaning.
- There's a pretty substantial number of people coming from Google with this question, which may justify action other than closing it. As of this writing, it has more than 50,000 views.
- The close reason seems very misleading to me. The question is clearly about computer hardware but is closed as off-topic, with only a comment from a moderator which does not cite [the relevant Meta post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6073/are-guessing-game-type-questions-allowed-on-su). Indeed, another Meta post from a different moderator [suggests that certain types of identification questions, such as those involving connectors, should not be closed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not/7651#7651).

As such, this question looks quite different from a typical "guessing game" question. Should this question be reopened, closed with a different reason, and/or historically locked, and what other options are available?

Comment: You cannot tell from the 50,000 views how many of them are "No, this isn't close to what I thought the question was about" from searches

Comment: Taking my mod hat off for a moment here... I still think we need "I couldn't be bothered to do even a cursory search on the Internet or to find my computer manual because it would have answered my question instantly" as a close reason. I suspect that the main reason why it got a misleading close reason is because we lost the "too localised" and "not a real question" close reasons sometime beforehand. For me this is in the same bucket as [show me the drivers!](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13055/requests-for-hardware-drivers) in that it shows a complete lack of effort.

Comment: Perhaps we should just leave the question closed, with a note that the question lacks adequate research effort? Despite the community thinking that it's a bad question, I think it's valuable enough for readers at large to justify a historical lock.

Comment: @Mokubai do you have any source to back up your claim? I've just checked the manual for my case (Antec) and I couldn't find any information on the meaning of leds, so I think I have a counterexample. As for that laptop, one needs to download a [200 MB ZIP file](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps/eManual/EManual_K53E_Z103.zip) and browse no less than 50 pages to find a 3-lines explanation which is not even entirely correct or understandable for the target audience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Indeed, another Meta post from a different moderator suggests that certain types of identification questions, such as those involving connectors, should not be closed.

Said moderator wrote a community FAQ to close those against.

In any case we can use the same tests

- Is there a minimum amount of effort put in?

*Every* manual in the past 40 years or so probably mentions what it is. So no

- Is it searchable?

Ok, maybe

- is it a practical, answerable question trying to solve a real practical problem other than curiosity?

No.

The only reason its not a guessing game question is it attempts to identify a common, standard and ubiquitous symbol.

I'd be disclined to reopen the question personally, and looks like other mods agree

Comment: If we were to do anything then I'd reopen and close it as a duplicate of [your Community FAQ](https://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer) and then slap a historical lock on it. Seems to be the cleanest and most solid way to say "we don't want these questions".

Comment: hmm.Not totally sure that's what I had in mind at the time when I created it - but it might work?

Comment: @Mokubai: Not a perfect solution (because we lack better close reasons), but I'd say that's a good idea nonetheless.

Comment: Or just leave it as is